# Inserir Vídeo em HTML

Tags: firefox, html5-video

Estou tentando inserir um vídeo em uma página que utiliza html e php.

tentei utilizar esta tag `<video src="video.mp4"></video>` tentei também como `<video><source="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`quando abro a página no meu navegador, ele funciona, porém quando abro através do site que ele está inserido, aparece a mensagem **Formato de Vídeo ou tipo MIME não suportado.**

Eu já tentei converter o vídeo para "Webm", mas continua a mesma mensagem.

O navegador é Firefox.

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "através do site que ele está inserido"?

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis a extensão não define o tipo, a extensão é mais para computadores Desktop e "magicmime" de servidores assumirem um que talvez seja um tipo especifico no momento de enviar o Content-Type via Apache por exemplo, mas se o arquivo estiver corrompido como presumo que esteja (já que o video funciona localmente) então o problema pode ser no upload ;)

Comment: Também compare o tamanho do arquivo local com o remoto, em bytes. Outra coisa que pode fazer para ver se está igual é calcular o md5 do arquivo, monte uma página simples fazendo essa checagem  e compare o local com o remoto: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_md5_file.asp (edit) só note que se o arquivo for muito grande, a rotina pode demorar muito...

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente você esta subindo o video via FTP e talvez esteja assumindo o upload como ASCII, para que não perca dados faça o upload como binário, por exemplo no Filezilla vá em:

<kbd>Transfer</kbd> > <kbd>Transfer type</kbd> > e troque <kbd>Auto</kbd> por <kbd>Binary</kbd>

Como na imagem:

[image: filezilla]

Então faça o upload novamente.

Comment: rapaz, até então eu não sabia para que servia esse tal de Binary aqui do meu Programa de FTP e por isso nunca arrisquei usar. Depois dessa resposta já saberei fazer uso caso necessário. +1

Comment: Então, eu não precisei fazer upload, porque é Windows Server, acessei a pasta direto e colei o vídeo lá

Comment: @Kcpirola89 abra o console do navegador e veja se aparece algum erro 404 ou 403 e me responde, se tiver outro erro informa, estou com uma suspeita, já que você esta usando IIS provavelmente.

Comment: O carregamento HTTP falhou com o status 404.

Comment: @Kcpirola89 em qual pasta esta o seu HTML e em qual pasta esta o seu video?

Comment: meu index é php, mas está na mesma pasta sim

Comment: @Kcpirola89 tem certeza que é a pasta correta? Qual o nome do arquivo do video e em qual pasta exatamente você colocou ele?

Comment: tanto o index.php quanto o arquivo de vídeo estão na mesma pasta, o vídeo chama-se "quantidade1.mp4"

Comment: @Kcpirola89 qual o nome da pasta completo? Tira um print da tela do console por favor.