# Problema ao baixar audio .wav Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Quando baixo o audio .mp3 ele funciona normalmente, porém quando é um audio .wav ele até baixa, porém quando vou escutar da um erro de execução. Se eu for no diretório onde está esse audio .wav, consigo ouvir ele normalmente, o problema é mesmo só quando baixo.
Código que faz o download

```
$filename = $arquivo;
$path = storage_path('app/ligacoes_snep/'.$filename);

return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
                'Content-Type' => 'audio/wav',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"']);
```

No Content-Type já tentei audio/vnd.wave, audio/wav, audio/wave, audio/x-wav.

Comment: Note que o content-type não vai afetar de fato a execução, talvez o audio quando você fez o upload tenha sido danificado.

Comment: Mas aí daria problema também quando eu fosse ouvir ele direto no diretório

Comment: Talvez o caminho que passou esteja errado, pode ser leitra maiuscula ou minuscula no nome do arquivo.

Comment: De qualquer forma tente assim: `return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
                'Content-Type' => 'audio/wav',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary',
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"']);`

Comment: eu capturo essa ligação em outro servidor e passo para o do meu sistema, o tempo todo utilizo a mesma variavel de nome.. e se fosse nome os casos de .mp3 dariam erro tbm

Comment: Não tem como afirmar nada, pode nem ter haver com o formato, pode ser só uma confusão sua. Não dá pra saber, de qualquer forma `content-type` não influencia, o problema deve ser outra coisa.

Comment: sem sucesso....

Comment: Não é alguma letra errada? Dê mais detalhes por favor, se não é dificil ajudar.

Comment: para matar essa dúvida, eu fui lá no servidor onde pego as ligações e peguei um nome fixo e aconteceu o mesmo problema :(

Comment: Fixo? Se refere a abrir o .wav diretamente via URL (http), sem laravel? Se for deve ser erro no upload via FTP. Luiz tenta isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226669/3635

Comment: Não não, quando digo fixo é que no filename eu passei um nome de uma ligação direto de lá, fui no servidor deu ctrl+c e colei no lugar de filename. Outra coisa, as ligações estão em .WAV e não .wav. Será que pode ser algo com isso?

Comment: sim, letra maiuscula e minuscula como eu disse no primeiro comentário pode ser um problema, pois se vc colocar na URL algo como `foo.wav`, mas o nome do arquivo for `Foo.Wav` não vai abrir em servidores Linux (a maior parte dos sites é linux)

Comment: eu passo o nome como ele vem, quando vou buscar no outro servidor, também utilizo .WAV e quando vou fazer download tbm utilizo .WAV, a minha dúvida sobre o .WAV maiusculo é que em outra parte do meu sistema eu salvo ligações .wav e não tenho nenhum problema ao baixar, porém é .wav e não .WAV. Tendesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. O meu problema não era com a extensão do arquivo, mas sim um código que eu estava executando antes do download

```
SSH::into('intranet')->run("rm -/var/www/html/intranet/storage/app/ligacoes_snep/", function($line){
          echo $line;
});
```

Obrigado pela atenção de todos..

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-downloads) (documentação do 5.5, mas compativel com o 5.2)

o melhor é você utilzar:

> return response()->download($pathToFile);
>
> return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
>
> return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

Ou ainda o

> return response()->file($pathToFile);

Comment: Sem sucesso : (